# Using variables in fieldnames - SQL Update statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to using Access 2010. I wish to execute the following sql update statement, but I have problems with the syntax. The table is called "Forecasts", and users will edit & update the qty forecasted.

Problem - The table fieldnames are 2014_1, 2014_2, 2014_3 ... to represent the different months, stored in an array. I have done abit of research and I believe the way to dynamically do this is:

```
Dim sqlString As String
    sqlString = "UPDATE Forecasts " & _
    " SET Branch_Plant=" & Me.txtBranch_Plant & _
    ", Item_Number_Short='" & Me.txtItem_Number_Short & "'" & _
    ", Description='" & Me.txtDescription & "'" & _
    ", UOM='" & Me.txtUOM & "'" & _
    ", Estimated_Cost=" & Me.txtEstimated_Cost & _
    ", Requesting_Business_Unit='" & Me.txtRequesting_Business_Unit & "'" & _
    ", End_Customer='" & Me.txtEnd_Customer & "'" & _
    ", Project='" & Me.txtProject & "'" & _
    ", Forecasts." & "[" & arrMonthToDisplay(0) & "]" = " & Me.txtProjectedJanVolume " & _
    " WHERE ID =" & Me.txtID.Tag

    MsgBox ("This is the output: " & sqlString)
    CurrentDb.Execute sqlString
```

It was working fine until this line was added

```
Forecasts." & "[" & arrMonthToDisplay(0) & "]" = " & Me.txtProjectedJanVolume
```

The msgbx output now shows: "False". Whats wrong with sqlString?

Please help! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
", Forecasts.[" & arrMonthToDisplay(0) & "] = " & Me.txtProjectedJanVolume & _
" WHERE ID =" & Me.txtID.Tag
```

Answer (score -1):

You compare string to string.
Change

```
", Forecasts." & "[" & arrMonthToDisplay(0) & "]" = " & Me.txtProjectedJanVolume " &
```

to

```
", Forecasts." & "[" & arrMonthToDisplay(0) & "] = " & " Me.txtProjectedJanVolume " &
```

Comment: actually, not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but the fact is - the = is out of quotation marks, which makes your query string a boolean expression

Comment: ", Forecasts." & "["  is most definitely wrong.  Why would you put an ampersand between "Forecasts." and "["?

Comment: Well, this question should go to topicstarter. I just tried to answer why he gets "False" instead of query text.